# How realistic are robot races on the moon this decade (circa 2015)?

Tags: lunar-landing, robotic-missions, xprize

My local paper has an article suggesting a possible event with [several robotic rovers leaving the same lander on the moon and trying to drive off for 500 meters (about a 1/3 of a mile) as fast as they can:](http://www.post-gazette.com/business/tech-news/2015/02/23/Pittsburgh-Astrobotic-CMU-first-competitor-to-send-payload-to-the-moon/stories/201502230027) the article makes it all seem fairly possible. They are competing for the [Google Lunar XPRIZE](http://lunar.xprize.org/).

So does this race scenario have an realistic chances of occurring or is all hype?

Answer (score 8):

If you mean within the next 10 years, with 2015 as a starting date, then it is not outside the realm of possibility.

The advent of cheaper launches does appear to be upon us. SpaceX is very close to recovering a first stage. Whether they can refly it cheaply is the key question. They are close to launching a Falcon Heavy, again if they can succeed and also recover/refly is the key question.

If they succeed, space flight costs will drop dramatically. At that point, cheaper missions become very possible.

If a moon launch was \$200 million (Say Atlas V launched) for launch services and with reuse of first stages drops to \$20-30 million a launch, the economics of it clearly change.

Google has been pushing for lunar rovers, and people are actively working on them. Will they succeed?  An interesting question.  The moon is a harsh mistress, so it is hard to know.  Odds seem to favour at least one succeeding out of the pack.

Can all these things come together within the next ten years? At the moment it looks likely, but many things can happen between now and then.

Comment: @JerardPuckett I was so happy when that just fit in perfectly.  :)

Comment: For the less well read the reference is [The Moon Is a Harsh Mistress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Moon_Is_a_Harsh_Mistress)

Comment: Looks like MathJax caught your dollar signs :)

Comment: @raptortech97 I escaped them with back slashes.  It renders properly for me.  What are you seeing?

Comment: Maybe it's just the app being funky, but I'm seeing "200" through "drops to" in italics.

Comment: @raptortech97 Nope, looks fine to me and all the dollar signs are escaped properly. Would you please refresh the page and see if that helps, otherwise please mention what browser and plugins you're using. It could be one of your plugins blocking some JavaScript or possibly also HTTPS problems if you're using plugins like HTTPS Everywhere.

Comment: @TildalWave I'm using the iOS app. When I switch to Chrome it works, so it must be an app issue. I'll see if I can figure out how to report that...

Comment: @raptortech97 Gotcha. I don't use iOS so I can't help you with that, but it's possible it's been overlooked with recent updates to the app. If you can't resolve it on your end I'd encourage you to report it as a bug either on [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com) or, I guess, also [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com) might be a suitable place. If you want, post a link here once you do that and I'll forward it to developers. Thanks!